# "How to embed resources" or "How to access a Resource"

Tags: embedded-resource, x++, dynamics-365

I am struggling with embedded resources or resources in general with Dynamics365. My goal is to add a xml-file as resource to a model and use that resource in some testcode.

I tried to add the xml as resource-element but it seems this does not embedd the xml into the compiled dll so i don't know how to pick up that xml-file in my testcode. Currently my testcode loads the xml from "C:\Temp\test.xml" where i copied my xml to, but thats not a viable solution and i thought adding the xml as resource would be ok. Or is there a better approach to this scenario ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class `SysResource` to interact with resources. I used the following code in one of my unit tests to load the content of a file resource into a file and create a `CommaStreamIo` instance from that file. You should be able to modify that to do your stuff with an xml file.

```cs
ResourceNode textFileResourceNode = SysResource::getResourceNode(resourceStr(MyTextFileResourceName));
str textFilename = SysResource::saveToTempFile(textFileResourceNode);

CommaStreamIo commaStreamIo = CommaStreamIo::constructForRead(File::UseFileFromURL(textFilename));
```

Also take a look at [reading a resource into a string](https://dynamicsuser.net/ax/f/developers/69306/reading-a-resource-into-a-string).

You could also take a look at how some of the standard resources are used. For example, there are several .xslt file resources that are used to transform bank statement formats.